# Change offset of an element when orientation changes (jQuery/CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a div that I want to dynamically arrange icons in based on size and shape of div, and size and numbers of icons. I've started by writing some code to place the first icon at the center of the div, then I plan to arrange the rest relative to the first one.

At this point, I'm just trying to get the first icon at the center to work. I can get it to work on initial page load, but when I change the orientation of my screen it is no longer at the center.

I tried adding a listener for "orientationchange" and calling my arrangeIcons() function again, but it isn't working. I also tried calling my arrangeIcons() function on a delay in case it was getting called before the offset property was updated on the div.

I have a border on the div to verify that it is resizing when the orientation changes.

I'd prefer not to reload the whole page, just rewrite the contents of the div.

I hope that makes sense.

I have included my css and js below.

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // call arrangeIcons() after page loads to
  // arrange them on the screen
  arrangeIcons();

  // when orientation changes, call arrangeIcons()
  // again to re-arrange the icons -- NOT WORKING
  $(window).on("orientationchange", function() {
    alert(screen.orientation);
    arrangeIcons();
  });

  // Find the center of the div and arrange the
  // icons based off of it
  function arrangeIcons() {

    // leftCoord is the "top" property plus half the width of the div
    // minus half the width of the icon
    var leftCoord = 
        ($('.icon-holder').offset()["top"] + 
        ($('.icon-holder').width()*.5)) - 
        $('.dev-icons').width()*.5;

    // topCoord is the "left" property plus half the height of the div
    // minus half the height of the icon
    var topCoord = 
        ($('.icon-holder').offset()["left"] +
         $('.icon-holder').height()*.5) - 
         $('.dev-icons').height()*.5;

    // set the offset of the icon
    $('.dev-icons').offset({
      "top" : topCoord,
      "left" : leftCoord
    });
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.dev-icons {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

.icon-holder {
  border: solid 1vw;
  height: 200vw;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Here is a link to the pen I am working in: http://codepen.io/RaneWrites/full/zZdaMb/

Comment: Not to disregard the work you've already done, but are you sure that this is a job for JS, and not for media queries based on [`orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#orientation)?

Comment: That's a good question and I'll have to look into it for updates. But for this project I am focusing on css and js/jquery.